# How to get the Window Handle from inside WndProc?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Maybe a stupid question, but...

I'm writing a `class` that should take care of keeping a Window (`FGuestHWnd`, from now on) visually anchored to a "Host Window" (`FHostHWnd`).

- `FGuestHWnd` and `HostHWnd` have NO parent/owner/child relationship.
- `FGuestHWnd` belongs to another process - don't care.
- `FHostHWnd` is the Window handle of a VCL `TWinControl`, so it's a child window inside my process. It can sit at any level inside the Parent/Child tree. For example, let's say it's a `TPanel`.

Now I have to "hook" `FHostHWnd`'s moving/resizing and call `SetWindowPos(FGuestHWnd...` after my custom calculation.

Resizing is straightforward: I can use `SetWindowLong(FHostHWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, ...)` to "redirect" `FHostHWnd`'s WndProc to my custom WindowPorcedure and trap `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`. This message is automatically sent to `FHostHWnd` when one of its ancestors get resized, because `FHostHWnd` is client-aligned.

MOVING, if I'm not missing something, is a little trickier because if i move the main form `FHostHWnd` is not really moved. It keeps the same position relative to its parent. So it is NOT notified in any way of an ancestor's movement.

My solution is to "redirect" ANY ANCESTOR's WndProc to a custom Window Procedure and trap WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING for "move" messages only.
In that case I could notify `FHostHWnd` with a custom message.
Some fields inside my class will keep track of the chain of Win Handles, Original WndProc addesses and new WndProc addresses.

Here is some code to explain my structure:

```
TMyWindowHandler = class(TObject)
private
  FHostAncestorHWndList: TList;
  FHostHWnd: HWND;
  FGuestHWnd: HWND;
  FOldHostAncestorWndProcList: TList;
  FNewHostAncestorWndProcList: TList;
  //...
  procedure HookHostAncestorWindows;
  procedure UnhookHostAncestorWindows;
  procedure HostAncestorWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
end;

procedure TMyWindowHandler.HookHostAncestorWindows;
var
  ParentHWnd: HWND;
begin
  ParentHWnd := GetParent(FHostHWnd);
  while (ParentHWnd > 0) do
  begin
    FHostAncestorHWndList.Insert(0, Pointer(ParentHWnd));
    FOldHostAncestorWndProcList.Insert(0, TFarProc(GetWindowLong(ParentHWnd,     GWL_WNDPROC)));
    FNewHostAncestorWndProcList.Insert(0, MakeObjectInstance(HostAncestorWndProc));
    Assert(FOldHostAncestorWndProcList.Count = FHostAncestorHWndList.Count);
    Assert(FNewHostAncestorWndProcList.Count = FHostAncestorHWndList.Count);
    if (SetWindowLong(ParentHWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, LongInt(FNewHostAncestorWndProcList[0])) = 0) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    ParentHWnd := GetParent(FHostHWnd);
  end;
end;
```

and here is The Handler:

```
procedure TMyWindowHandler.HostAncestorWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  pNew: PWindowPos;
begin
  case Msg.Msg of
    WM_DESTROY: begin
      UnHookHostAncestorWindows;
    end;
    WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING: begin
      pNew := PWindowPos(Msg.LParam);
      // Only if the window moved!
      if ((pNew.flags and SWP_NOMOVE) = 0) then
      begin
        //
        // Do whatever
        //
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Msg.Result := CallWindowProc(???, ???, Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam );
end;
```

**My question is**:

How can I get the Window Handle from inside my WindowProcedure when I finally invoke `CallWindowProc`?
(If I had the Window Handle I could also find it in `FOldHostAncestorWndProcList`, then lookup the right Old-WndProc-pointer in `FHostAncestorHWndList`)
Or, as an alternative, how to get the CURRENT method pointer so that I can find it in `FNewHostAncestorWndProcList` and lookup the HWND in `FHostAncestorHWndList`.

Or do you suggest other solutions?

Notice that I'd like to keep everything HWND-oriented, not VCL/TWinControl-aware.
In other words, my application should only instantiate TMyWindowHandler passing to it the two `HWND`s (host and guest).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I would not use `MakeObjectInstance` here. `MakeObjectInstance` is useful if you wish to bind the instance to a single window handle. The magic of `MakeObjectInstance` is the generation of a thunk that forwards window procedure calls to instance methods. And in doing so, the window handle is not passed to the instance method because the assumption is that the instance already knows its associated window handle. That's certainly the case for `TWinControl`, the prime use case of `MakeObjectInstance`.

Now, you are binding it to multiple window handles. When the instance method executes you have no way to know which of the many window handles is associated with this method execution. That is the very crux of your problem.

My recommendation is to abandon `MakeObjectInstance` because it does not meet your needs. Instead, define a plain window procedure of this form:

```
function WindowProc(hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; 
  lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
```

When you implement the window procedure like this, you do receive a window handle, as you desire.

You may well need to keep a global list of `TMyWindowHandler` instances so that you can lookup the `TMyWindowHandler` instance associated with the window passed to your window procedure. Alternatively you could use [`SetProp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633568.aspx) to associate some data with the window.

Note that the way you are sub-classing windows has various problems. The `SetWindowSubclass` function is provided to avoid these problems. More details here: [Subclassing Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx).

Comment: Thank you David. But doesn't `MakeObjectInstance` exists specifically to address this problem? It seems the exact way VCL itself binds a `TWinControl`'s `WndProc`.

Comment: I've expanded on that. `MakeObjectInstance` is your problem. That's used by `AllocateHwnd` and `TWinControl.Create` to form a one-to-one relationship between a window and an instance. Your problem has a many-to-one window to instance relationship. And so `MakeObjectInstance` is no good at all.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to pass user-defined data to `MakeObjectInstance()`.  It takes a closure as input, and a closure can be manipulated using the `TMethod` record, so you can set its `Data` field to point at whatever you want and it will be accessible via the `Self` pointer inside the method body.  For example:

```
type
  PMyWindowHook = ^TMyWindowHook;
  TMyWindowHook = record
    Wnd: HWND;
    OldWndProc: TFarProc;
    NewWndProc: Pointer;
    Handler: TMyWindowHandler;
  end;

  TMyWindowHandler = class
  private
    FHostAncestorHWndList: TList;
    FHostAncestorWndProcList: TList;
    FHostHWnd: HWND;
    FGuestHWnd: HWND;
    //...
    procedure HookHostAncestorWindows;
    procedure UnhookHostAncestorWindows;
    procedure HostAncestorWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  end;

procedure TMyWindowHandler.HookHostAncestorWindows;
var
  ParentHWnd: HWND;
  Hook: PMyWindowHook;
  NewWndProc: Pointer;
  M: TWndMethod;
begin
  ParentHWnd := GetParent(FHostHWnd);
  while ParentHWnd <> 0 do
  begin
    M := HostAncestorWndProc;
    New(Hook);
    try
      TMethod(M).Data := Hook;
      Hook.Hwnd := ParentHWnd;
      Hook.OldWndProc := TFarProc(GetWindowLong(ParentHWnd, GWL_WNDPROC));
      Hook.NewWndProc := MakeObjectInstance(M);
      Hook.Handler := Self;
      FHostAncestorWndProcList.Insert(0, Hook);
      try
        SetLastError(0);
        if SetWindowLongPtr(ParentHWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, LONG_PTR(Hook.NewWndProc)) = 0 then
        begin
          if GetLastError() <> 0 then
          begin
            FreeObjectInstance(Hook.NewWndProc);
            RaiseLastOSError;
          end;
        end;
      except
        FHostAncestorWndProcList.Delete(0);
        raise;
      end;
    except
      Dispose(Hook);
      raise;
    end;
    ParentHWnd := GetParent(ParentHWnd);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyWindowHandler.UnhookHostAncestorWindows;
var
  Hook: PMyWindowHook;
begin
  while FHostAncestorWndProcList.Count > 0
  begin
    Hook := PMyWindowHook(FHostAncestorWndProcList.Items[0]);
    FHostAncestorWndProcList.Delete(0);
    SetWindowLongPtr(Hook.Hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, LONG_PTR(Hook.OldWndProc));
    FreeObjectInstance(Hook.NewWndProc);
    Dispose(Hook);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyWindowHandler.HostAncestorWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  Hook: PMyWindowHook;
  pNew: PWindowPos;
begin
  Hook := PMyWindowHook(Self);
  case Msg.Msg of
    WM_DESTROY: begin
      Msg.Result := CallWindowProc(Hook.Wnd, Hook.OldWndProc, Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam);
      Hook.Handler.FHostAncestorWndProcList.Remove(Hook);
      SetWindowLongPtr(Hook.Hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, LONG_PTR(Hook.OldWndProc));
      FreeObjectInstance(Hook.NewWndProc);
      Dispose(Hook);
      Exit;
    end;
    WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING: begin
      pNew := PWindowPos(Msg.LParam);
      // Only if the window moved!
      if (pNew.flags and SWP_NOMOVE) = 0 then
      begin
        //
        // Do whatever
        //
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Msg.Result := CallWindowProc(Hook.Wnd, Hook.OldWndProc, Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam);
end;
```

Granted, this is not an ideal setup.  `SetWindowSubClass()` would be a much better choice than `SetWindowLong(GWL_WNDPROC)`.  The hook procedure gives you the `HWND`, and you can specify user-defined data.  No hacks needed.  For example:

```
type
  TMyWindowHandler = class
  private
    FHostAncestorHWndList: TList;
    FHostAncestorWndProcList: TList;
    FHostHWnd: HWND;
    FGuestHWnd: HWND;
    //...
    procedure HookHostAncestorWindows;
    procedure UnhookHostAncestorWindows;
    class function HostAncestorWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData): LRESULT; stdcall; static;
  end;

procedure TMyWindowHandler.HookHostAncestorWindows;
var
  ParentHWnd: HWND;
begin
  ParentHWnd := GetParent(FHostHWnd);
  while ParentHWnd <> 0 do
  begin
    FHostAncestorWndProcList.Insert(0, Pointer(ParentWnd));
    try
      if not SetWindowSubclass(ParentWnd, @HostAncestorWndProc, 1, DWORD_PTR(Self)) then
        RaiseLastOSError;
    except
      FHostAncestorWndProcList.Delete(0);
      raise;
    end;
    ParentHWnd := GetParent(ParentHWnd);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyWindowHandler.UnhookHostAncestorWindows;
begin
  while FHostAncestorWndProcList.Count > 0 do
  begin
    RemoveWindowSubclass(HWND(FHostAncestorWndProcList.Items[0]), @HostAncestorWndProc, 1);
    FHostAncestorWndProcList.Delete(0);
  end;
end;

class function TMyWindowHandler.HostAncestorWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  pNew: PWindowPos;
begin
  case uMsg of
    WM_NCDESTROY: begin
      RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, @HostAncestorWndProc, 1);
      TMyWindowHandler(dwRefData).FHostAncestorWndProcList.Remove(Pointer(hWnd));
    end;
    WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING: begin
      pNew := PWindowPos(Msg.LParam);
      // Only if the window moved!
      if (pNew.flags and SWP_NOMOVE) = 0 then
      begin
        //
        // Do whatever
        //
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
end;
```

Comment: +1 for the interesting info on `MakeObjectInstance`.
I ended up using `SetWindowSubclass`. Much cleaner.

Comment: Despite anything else, this is a valuable example (in Delphi) on how to use `SetWindowSubclass`.